# How can you not cut off long text depending on the size of your window in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

When your widget (in my case this label) has too long of text then how can you make it so it doesn't get cut off, depending on the the size of the root window (the main window)? I know that you can use `wraplength=` attribute to wrap the text if it gets to long, although this only works if you know the length of the window before hand. So, what would you do if the user resizes the window, I know how to dynamically change the widget sizes if the window size changes, but not the text inside that widget.

> Example of text getting cut off without using `wraplength=`.

[image: Please view image]

> Example of text using `wraplength=400` not fitting the window if the window gets resized.

[image: Please view image2]

As you can see from the image `wraplength=` doesn't always work. Also, if was to make the window smaller then the `wraplength=` then we would have the same problem of text getting cut off. So, is their a way to dynamically change the wrap length of a text depending on how wide the user has the window?

Comment: Did you try binding `<Configure>` on the label and update the `wraplength` option in the event callback?  Or use `Text` widget instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `wraplength` value to the width of the label (you can use `.winfo_width()` method to get it. You would also need to update the `wraplength` every time the window is being resized (the `"<Configure>"` event).

So, you should do something like this (a bit simplified version):

```
import tkinter as tk


def enter():
    label.configure(text=entry.get())

def copy_to_clipboard():
    root.clipboard_append(entry.get())

def update_wraplength(_event):
    label.configure(wraplength=label.winfo_width())

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
entry = tk.Entry(frame1)
entry.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
tk.Button(frame1, text="Enter", command=enter)\
                .pack(side="left")
frame1.pack(fill="x")

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
label = tk.Label(frame2)
label.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
tk.Button(frame2, text="Copy to Clipoard", command=copy_to_clipboard)\
                .pack(side="left")
frame2.pack(fill="x")

root.bind("<Configure>", update_wraplength)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshots:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Another option is to use a `Text` widget instead of a `Label`. Perhaps, you will have to set its state to `disabled`, as well as change some other attributes (e.g. `background` or `borderwidth`):

```
Text(root, state="disabled", ...)
```